# android - data sharing via intent - send and receive

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to figure out how complex user tasks are implemented in Android.

For example, consider (taken from this [paper](http://www.enck.org/pubs/nadkarni-ccs13.pdf)):

[image]

Here the email app has to sign a document. It sends contract.doc to DocuView. DocuSign needs a pdf. So Docuview interacts with WordToPdf to get a pdf. Then DocuView interacts with DocuSign to get a signed pdf. In the end, signed pdf is returned to email app.

I have been going through the [data sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) tutorials.

I understand that between two apps, one app has a file provider (which holds the uri's) and the other app can get the uri through intent, along with per-uri permissions.

What I want to ask is :

how can an app receiving a uri modify the data and send the result back (like between DocuView and WordToPdf) ?

Also how does forwarding work ? Email might share URI with DocuView, so how does DocuView forward that to WordToPdf for its use ?

(this kind of forms the building block for this diagram; each of the interactions are send and receive)

Comment: If the URI is to a local file and it has write permissions, it can just edit the file at that URI.

Comment: @GabeSechan Do you think such tasks modify the original file via URI or create a new file somehow and return it back (like contract.pdf) ?

Comment: Either would obviously work.  If I had my guess they would either modify the original file or take a location where to place the new file.  I doubt they'd want the new file to be in the editor's file quota.

Comment: @GabeSechan Oh so you mean .. it could be like ... instead of 1 .. DocuView could send 2 URIs to WordToPdf .. one to read from, and one to write to. The editor never has the files in its directory ... just reads / writes URIs based on permissions.

Comment: It could.  That way the original file wouldn't be overwritten.  But I can't promise that any individual app does work this way.

Comment: @GabeSechan Also how does forwarding work ? Email might share URI with DocuView, so how does DocuView forward that to WordToPdf for its use ?